# Why can't I use JPA without h2

Tags: spring, jpa, h2, boot

I have just started studying Spring and there are some things that are not clear to me.
I have the pom done like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I start the application the following error is thrown:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

---

if I add this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then the app works

I would like to understand if h2 is needed for Jpa to work, since in many examples I've seen usually this dependency is not added to make the application work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring starters and don't specify any particular database in pom.xml, then Spring Data will configure a default H2 (in memory) database for you. You don't need to put the h2 artifact in pom.xml.

However in your pom.xml there is already MySql artifact added. In this case you must tell Spring which database should be use for JPA. For example by adding datasource details in application.properties.

If you decide to use MySQL then the artifact in pom.xml would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The datasource definition in application.properties would be:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<some_db_name>
spring.datasource.username=<some_username>
spring.datasource.password=<some_password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

To let Spring Data create/update the database during startup from entity classes use following properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

If you want to create the database from a DDL script and insert some data from a script file instead - use following properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Spring will use the default scripts schema.sql and data.sql located on the classpath (default). More detailed Spring docu: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Comment: If I remove the dependency of h2 and thus configure the datasource in application.properties:

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db_example

    spring.datasource.username=myusername

    spring.datasource.password=mypassword
    
the application doesn't start and I have the same error as before.

Comment: Even if I add this: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, it doesn't work.

Comment: @UltraKing I have added details in the answer. Pls check.

Comment: Even after adding the two lines to the application properties the situation has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in the Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source(tab) --> Source folders on build path
I noticed that in the Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Source(tab) --> Source folders on build path, in the src/main/resources the excluded item was marked with **.
I removed it and now everything works.