# Spring Boot application not running-Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I was running a Spring Boot application and I got the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

- I am using **MySQL 8.0**
- I am using **Spring Tool Suite (STS) 4.17.2**

This is the **entire console output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.0.4)[0;39m

[2m2023-03-15T12:59:50.801+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.s.app.SpringbootBackendApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting SpringbootBackendApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 11308 (G:\Reek\development\Java\STS\springboot-backend\target\classes started by REEK in G:\Reek\development\Java\STS\springboot-backend)
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:50.812+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.s.app.SpringbootBackendApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:51.967+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:52.026+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:52.910+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:52.931+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:52.932+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.159+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.160+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2192 ms
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.288+05:30[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.311+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.377+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-03-15T12:59:53.420+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I am using Spring Tool Suite and this is my current **folder structure**

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8notF.png)

This is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-backend</name>
    <description>Spring Boot RESTful web services</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my **application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I do not understand what's wrong, please help me here.

I tried to run the application and I was expecting that it would run without any errors

Comment: application.properties looks good but most probably is not on the classpath. Check similar question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733313/why-cant-i-use-jpa-without-h2

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have application.properties in

`G:\Reek\development\Java\STS\springboot-backend\target\classes`

If that is indeed the case,You need to add:

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

in <build> child